# Не читается переменная

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать график обновляемый из БД.
Сделал практически всё, встал на одном моменте.
При попытке передать данные из переменной (data_result), ничего не происходит.
Если вставить вместо переменной значения, то работает.
В чем моя ошибка?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
var dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['1470139847',1.11,1.11,1.11,1.11],
['1470139847',1.11,1.11,1.11,1.11],
['1470139847',1.11,1.11,1.11,1.11]
  // Treat first row as data as well.
], true);

var options = {
  legend:'none'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
var value_arr = new Array();
var inv_date = '';
var data_result = '';

chart.draw(dataChart, options);
updateChart(dataChart, chart, options, value_arr, inv_date);
}
function updateChart(dataChart, chart, options, value_arr, inv_date) {
    var option = $('#option').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'/ajax.php',
        data:({
            option: option
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            var rateVal = data.split(';');
            $('#rateVal').text(data);
            value_arr.push(rateVal[0]);
            inv_date = rateVal[1];
        }
    });
    if (value_arr.length == 4) {
        data_result = "'" + inv_date + "'," + value_arr[0] + ',' + value_arr[1] + ',' + value_arr[2] + ',' + value_arr[3];
        dataChart.addRow([data_result]);
        chart.draw(dataChart, options);
        var value_arr = new Array();
    }


setTimeout(function(){updateChart(dataChart, chart, options, value_arr, inv_date)}, 1000);
   }



</script>
            <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

---

Требовалось перевести данные в Float для графика

Comment: У Вас не хватает названий для имен переменных и параметров? `value_arr` - глобальная переменная, параметр функции `updateChart`, локальная переменная в функции `updateChart`.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, как вы формируете данные для передачи в addRow.

Когда вы делаете

```
data_result = "'" + inv_date + "'," + value_arr[0] + ',' + value_arr[1] + ',' + value_arr[2] + ',' + value_arr[3];
dataChart.addRow([data_result]);
```

в функцию addRow приходит вот что (обратите внимание на кавычки):

```
addRow(["'foo',bar,foo2,bar2"])
```

то есть массив с одним элементом - строкой. Вероятно, это не то, чего вы ожидали.

Нужно как-то так:

```
data_result  = [inv_date,value_arr[0],value_arr[1],value_arr[2],value_arr[3]];
dataChart.addRow(data_result);
```

или еще проще

```
dataChart.addRow([inv_date,value_arr[0],value_arr[1],value_arr[2],value_arr[3]]);
```

Comment: Не в этом причина. Причина в этой строке dataChart.addRow([data_result]);, а именно в переменной data_result

Когда вместо переменной ставишь значения, то график обновляется

Comment: @Nemilus у вас updateChart срабатывает каждую секунду, так и задумано?

Comment: @Nemilus и еще покажите код функции addRow или уточните, в каком виде нужно передать туда данные? Или как вы подставляли значения, что у вас работало? Я, кажется, понял ошибку, но нужно уточнение, чтобы окончательно сформулировать ответ.

Comment: да, так и задумано

Comment: Кода функции нет, это графики от гугл https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#example

Comment: В таком виде ['1470139847',1.11,1.11,1.11,1.11]. Если вывести эту переменную и потом полученные данные вставить в addRow,то график обновляется

Comment: @Nemilus обновил ответ

Comment: Не помогло. У меня была мысль, что может быть данные из переменной как-то по другому нужно передавать. Вся проблема заключается в переменных, если просто данные. то все отлично работает

Comment: Хм. Ну ошибку я точно описал, без сомнений. Выведите в console.log то что у вас передается в addRow